# What is the output of the below code and how it works?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fun(int a, float b)
{
    int c;
    c = a + b;
    printf("Value ----- c %d", c);
}

int main()
{
   void (*foo) (int, int) = &fun;

   (*foo)(3,2);
    return 0;
}
```

I just want to know how this code flow works.
the above code prints 3 as output i am not sure how it is working

Comment: Your function pointer has the wrong types for arguments, btw.

Comment: Mismatching argument types leads to *undefined behavior*. Doesn't the compiler issue any warnings? [It should](https://godbolt.org/z/da6Tvr6sf).

Comment: Don't ignore compiler warnings

Comment: OT: `(*foo)(3,2);` can be written `foo(3,2);` which IMO is easier to read

Comment: Would you still ask this question if the output had been 5 ?

Comment: Well... it _is_ undefined behavior but only because the code is invalid C and any binary generated from code containing invalid C is per definition undefined behavior. [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code exhibits undefined behaviour stemming from the assignment of a `void (*)(int, float)` to a `void (*)(int, int)`.

This means the program is free to do anything it wants to. The output could be 64, a SIGSEGV, or the deletion of your hard drive. There's no way to know.

Always enable your compiler's warnings. It would have caught this error. With gcc, you could use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror`.

Comment: This was an interview question, then what should be our answer to this question? I knew that it will give warnings about compatibility but the interviewer not convinced

Comment: It's undefined behaviour, so the program is free to do anything it wants to. The output could be 64, a SEGFAULT, or the deletion of your hard drive. There's no way to know. That is the answer I would give in an interview.

Answer (score 3):

Your program invoked *undefined behavior* by using a pointer having incompatible type to call a function. (pointer `void (*)(int, int)` is used to call a function `void fun(int a, float b)`, the type of the 2nd parameter differs)

The reason for this paticular result *may be* that you are using a calling convention where floating-point arguments are passed in different ways (different registers, for example) than integer arguments and there happened to be zero or some small value in such area to pass floating-point values.